# Server 2008 R2 - Disconnected Network Drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a 2k8 R2 server. I cannot get the mapped network drive to stay connected even though it is located on the same server that is sharing the drive. For whatever reason it points to the share drive and not the local location. It says disconnected drive, but will load immediately when opened. It does not appear in the net use command or in reg edit. I have turned off the timeout timer completely. It will not disconnect to remap stating this network connection does not exist. It will show as connected when restarted, but will drop eventually. I need a fix so that it stays connected. Please help.